# How do you handle dependency in api testing?

Tags: php, codeception

I have large api that I want to wirte api tests for each endpoint.
How should I handle testing endpoints that depend on id from other endpoints?

In our application we have to create client first then branch then products then order for that branch.
so if I am testing

```
POST /clients
POST /branches
POST /products
POST /orders
```

should I write create client before every test for each endpoint?

Comment: Alternatively you could create client record directly in database by using Db or Doctrine module. Modules for other data stores exist too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL PHP for this

Follow : https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php

Or you can run this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com"); // API url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // for get retutn requsert
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // for use post requsert
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['key'=>'value']); // for post data
$res = curl_exec($ch); // for close requset
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    var_dump(curl_error($ch)); // for print error
} else {
    print_r($res); // for print result
}
```

Comment: I am not asking about how post data to url. I am asking about how to manage dependency between tests